# How to find whether a software (which may *not* be in the PATH) is pre-installed or not?

Tags: software-installation, path

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~> which qmake
which: no qmake in (/opt/qtcreator-2.0.92/bin/:/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/bin/:/opt/qtcreator-2.0.92/bin/:/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/bin/:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin)

anisha@linux-dopx:~> locate qmake
anisha@linux-dopx:~>
```

Is there any other way by which I can confirm whether a software is installed or not, considering the clause that it is currently not in the PATH?

Comment: Since locate uses a database and does not restrict to $PATH, if the database is up to date, no need to do more. (you can use `locate -eb \\filename` to find only existing files with exact match)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `whereis`. It looks in all places that make sense for binaries (when `-b` is used), even if they are not included in your `$PATH`. For example `whereis -b ifconfig` returns `/sbin/ifconfig`, even though `/sbin` is not in my `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, what does this output mean now? Command: `anisha@linux-dopx:~> whereis qmake`
Output: `qmake:`

Comment: with `-b` also it is returning the same.

Comment: @Anisha: means it is not installed. You may want to install `qt-devel` to get `qmake`

Comment: It means that it cannot find `qmake` in all the paths that it looks for. From the man page: "whereis then attempts  to locate the desired program in a list of standard Linux places". So that could also mean that `qmake` is installed but in an unusual place. You can also try `find`. For example `find / -executable -type f -name ifconfig 2>/dev/null` looks for the `ifconfig` executable file, starting from the root directory. Just replace `ifconfig` with `qmake`.

Comment: Thanks @nico, I did: `cnf qmake` which resulted in `The program 'qmake' can be found in following packages:
  * libqt4-devel [ path: /usr/bin/qmake, repository: zypp (openSUSE-11.3 11.3-1.82) ]
  * libqt4-devel [ path: /usr/bin/qmake, repository: zypp (repo-oss) ]
  * libqt4-devel [ path: /usr/bin/qmake, repository: zypp (Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82) ]

Try installing with:
    sudo zypper install libqt4-devel
`

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the sole definition of the word "***installed***". There are several ways to interpret it.

- A typical and most proper way to "install" a program is to use a package manager tool(s). These vary from distribution to distribution: on Gentoo, there is `emerge` and and a bunch of other helpful programs around *portage*; on Debian-based systems (like Ubuntu), there are `apt-<something>` tools and so on. These tools are what you should use whenever possible - both for installation and **searching for available/installed software** - their main job on the system is to maintain all the information about your official software.
- Software that is not available in the repositories can also be installed by its own specific installation scripts. Such software will not be automatically seen by the system management tools - which can cause various problems. To find components of such programs, you are left to use tools like `locate`, `find`, `which` or `whereis`.
- You can also build a program, place it "by hand" and adjust your environment (like `PATH`) so that it becomes usable. From both the user's and the system's point of view it can be much different, slightly different or not different at all compared to the previous approach.

In your case, you should distinguish between *finding a binary* and *determining if a certain **package** is installed*. For the practical part of finding a binary, you can just use `which` or `whereis`. Note that **the `PATH` environmental variable can be different for root and non-root** users. If you want to determine if a *package* is installed (using the first interpretation of that word), use your distribution's package management software.

Comment: Thanks, that's correct, I should have use the package manager, too, to figure out whether `qmake` is installed or not.