# How to find the installation path for a software under linux?

Tags: linux, software-installation

Under linux, I launch a software by typing, e.g., fluidplot. How can I find the installation path for this software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [18472](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/how-to-find-whether-a-software-which-may-not-be-in-the-path-is-pre-installed/18472)

Answer (score 98):

You can use:

```
which fluidpoint
```

to see where it is executing from (if it's in your $PATH). Or:

```
find / -name fluidpoint 2> /dev/null
```

to look for a file named fluipoint and redirect errors on virtual filesystems.

Usually they are in `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/local/bin` or `~` as a hidden directory.

From Manual:

```
NAME
       which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.

SYNOPSIS
       which [options] [--] programname [...]
```

Full manual: https://linux.die.net/man/1/which

Comment: or check to see if the program is actually an alias, e.g. `alias fluidpoint`,

Comment: @Chad Some versions of `which` (e.g. the one built in to ZSH) will do that for you

Comment: @Michael excellent to know. Because of your comment, I just discovered that newer versions of bash also do this.  +1 to your comment.

Comment: The "Usually they are ..." line is pretty disingenuous, additional software should be in `/opt/*` or `/usr/local/bin`.  `~` is your home directory, I'm confused why you call it "hidden".

Comment: Sorry to be ambiguous, I mean `~/.dir`. The hidden directory is below the home directory. And I completely forgot about `/usr/local/bin` dop.

Answer (score 19):

If you use an RPM based distribution (CentOS, RHEL, SUSE, openSUSE) you can use rpm -ql

Example:

```
rpm -ql findutils
/bin/find
/usr/bin/find
/usr/bin/xargs
/usr/share/doc/packages/findutils
/usr/share/doc/packages/findutils/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/packages/findutils/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/packages/findutils/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/packages/findutils/README
/usr/share/doc/packages/findutils/THANKS
/usr/share/doc/packages/findutils/TODO
/usr/share/info/find.info.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/find.1.gz
```

Things aren't installed to locations in the Linux/UNIX world like they are in the Windows (and even somewhat in the Mac) world. They are more distributed. Binaries are in `/bin` or `/sbin`, libraries are in `/lib`, icons/graphics/docs are in /share, configuration is in `/etc` and program data is in `/var`.

The `/bin`,`/lib`,`/sbin` contain the core applications needed for booting and the `/usr` contains all the other user and system applications.

Answer (score 14):

Just to add some point to @djsumdog's answer, if you are using DPKG based dist, like Ubuntu, you can use

```
dpkg --status some_package
```

to check what it is about, and

```
dpkg --listfiles some_package
```

to check what files are included/relevant to this package. It's for packages that don't have a binary to run, like `libnss3`. And

```
dpkg --search some_file
```

to find what package includes this file.

For example, `dpkg --listfiles libnss3` gives me:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libsoftokn3.chk
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libnssckbi.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libnsssysinit.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libfreebl3.chk
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libnssdbm3.chk
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libnssdbm3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libsoftokn3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libfreebl3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss3.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libnss3
/usr/share/doc/libnss3/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libnss3/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libnss3
```

Note that the folders are not only owned by this packages, but by others too. Just check the files.

And reversely, `dpkg --search libnss3.so` gives me:

```
firefox: /usr/lib/firefox/libnss3.so
thunderbird: /usr/lib/thunderbird/libnss3.so
libnss3:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss3.so
libnss3-1d:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss3.so.1d
```

Answer (score 6):

The `whereis` command locates the binary, source, and manual-page files for a command, and the `type` command tells what exactly the shell executes when you run a certain command.

Try `whereis -l fluidplot` in your case. If it only returns "fluidplot:", but no path, that means the software is not installed. Note that this does not include files that may be hidden within the home folder under `~/.local/share/` (in my case).

Found on [Linux Screw](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2007/08/29/find-out-where-unixlinux-executable-binary-is-located/)

Comment: Re: "this does not include...", it's not clear whether _this_ refers to _type_, _whereis_, or both.

Comment: @agc I merged the three lines into a single paragraph; is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, it's much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

On Arch based systems:

```
pacman -Qo <somefile>
```

Will give you the package that owns *somefile*.

```
pacman -Ql <package>
```

Will list the location of all the files that comes with a given package

Answer (score 1):

You just simply type the command in Linux terminal **whereis toolsname**. I have searched like this: `whereis ping`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `which` ([which probably isn't the right choice unless you're using csh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)) you can use `command -v fluidplot` to get the shell to boune like shell to tell you what it would do if you asked it to run the command (`fluidplot` in this example).

Some examples for me:

```
$ command -v ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
$ command -v cat
/bin/cat
$ test_func() {
> :
> }
$ command -v test_func
test_func
$ which test_func
/usr/bin/which: no test_func in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin)
$ if command -v noSuchFile; then echo "It exists"; else echo "does not exist"; fi
does not exist
```

so you can also use it to test if a command would even be found and attempted to run.  Since most of us use Bourne-like shells (e.g., bash or zsh) this is often preferable to `which`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the main goal is being missed, in that links are scattered around but the actual app is in one place. How to find?

1. whereis "symlink"
   result will be like : /usr/bin/"symlink"
   look at the location of the symlink, then run
2. ls -al /usr/bin |grep "symlink"
   this will produce the line that tells you where the app is located, such as

postman -> /opt/Postman/Postman

Answer (score -1):

You can try to run:

```
ps aux | grep "THE_NAME_OF_A_PROGRAM"
```

There are pretty good chances you will see the path to the program (if it's running)