# How to find path where jdk installed?

Tags: rhel, java

I've installed `jdk1.7.0.rpm` package in RHEL6.
Where I do find the path to execute my first java program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [18472](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/how-to-find-whether-a-software-which-may-not-be-in-the-path-is-pre-installed/18472)

Comment: Hi, Mohammad. It's not a stupid question, but one that has been answered in several places already - like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19369/how-to-find-the-installation-path-for-a-software-under-linux) or [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/how-to-find-whether-a-software-which-may-not-be-in-the-path-is-pre-installed/18472).

Comment: Just an PS: on MacOS, Java is usually installed at '/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home', where the version number could be different.

Answer (score 88):

Try either of the two:

> $ which java
>
> $ whereis java

For your first java program read this tutorial:

["Hello World!" for Solaris OS and Linux](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html)

Comment: Note these commands give different results.  If you are interested in the non-symlink path use whereis java.

Comment: I don't really think this answers the question. The `java` binary gets installed with the JRE, but if you're doing development you need JDK, which isn't necessarily installed in `which java` (which in my case is /usr/bin).

Comment: `type java` is a more cross-platform method, as it's built into every major posix shell.

Answer (score 31):

On RHEL7, you can use `locate`:

```
locate openjdk
```

or `find`:

```
find / -iname "*openjdk-*"
```

and it led me to the `/usr/lib/jvm/` directory which contained the directories:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/
jre/
jre-1.8.0/
jre-1.8.0-openjdk/
jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/
jre-openjdk/
```

Each of these contain a `bin/java`

To find the full path of the symbolic link use:

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

*Credit: [Answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290554/find-java-home-and-set-it-on-rhel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: This gave me mostly JDK6 even though `java -version` gave me 1.8. There was one link to the JDK8 folder near the top.

Comment: Thank you. The ```readlink -f $(which java)``` was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 17):

You can list the installed files with

```
rpm -ql packagename
```

You will see somewhere a `bin` directory with `java executable`

But if the JDK RPM was correctly installed you should already find `java` in you path.

Try

```
javac MyFirstJavaClass.java
```

and if everything compiles

```
java MyFirstClass
```

(If you didn't change anything the current directory `.` should already be in your class path)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Answer (score 13):

Since this question is RPM specific, `rpm` is the way to get started (as [answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21691/63264) by [@Matteo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10616/matteo)).

**rpm flags**

```
-q is short for --query
-l is short for --list
```

**Example**

```
rpm -ql jdk1.8.0_20 | grep "jdk1.8.0_20/bin$"
```

> ```
> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin
> ```

Knowing this may be desirable for setting a user or application's `$JAVA_HOME` variable. This is often needed when a system has multiple versions of java installed, or multiple distributions of java installed, such as [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) and [Oracle/Sun](https://www.oracle.com/java/index.html).

**`$JAVA_HOME` Example**

In the `~/.bash_profile`, or related file (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, `.cshrc`, `setenv.sh`), something similar to the below may be used.

```
JAVA_HOME='/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20'
export JAVA_HOME
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

---

If you would like more control over where Java gets installed, such as in `/opt`, then the tarball can be used instead of the RPM file.

---

*Other similar questions, are asking about how to find any binary or file, in the general case.*

Comment: In general, I highly recommend using the [mlocate](https://fedorahosted.org/mlocate/) package for finding things on a Red Hat based Linux's file system.